# How to load saved item from JSON file in java

Tags: java, json, swing

I am making an app where user can change `theme (dark and light mood)` as per his convenience. And the `theme` that the user chooses will be saved and the saved `theme` will be there when the app is opened again later.

I have saved the data to file using `JSON`.
And when the user clicks on the `theme` change button, the data will be written to the `file`.

The code of the theme:

```
private void darkTheme() {
    FlatDarkLaf.setup(); 
    UIManager.put("TextField.foreground", new ColorUIResource(Color.WHITE));
    UIManager.put("Label.foreground", new ColorUIResource(Color.WHITE));
    UIManager.put("Button.foreground", new ColorUIResource(Color.WHITE));               
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(contentPane);
    for(int i=0; i<arList.size(); i++) {
        ((JLabel)arList.get(i).getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }
}
```

And the Code for the theme change and write to the file button:

```
btnDark.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String path = "resources/config.cfg";
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try {
                json.put("Theme", "darkTheme();");
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
     
            try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(path))) {
                out.write(json.toString());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            darkTheme();
        }
    });
```

I can read the file but can't `Load` the save data.
Here the code for read the file:

```
private void readData() {
    try {
    String path = "resources/config.cfg";
        InputStream is = Button.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
        if (is == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Cannot find resource file " + path);
        }
        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(is);
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(tokener);
       // object.getString("darkTheme();");
        object.getJSONObject("Theme");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me how to do this correctly.

Comment: what is `json.put("Theme", "darkTheme();");` supposed to do?

Comment: I am totally new to JSON and I have find an example from internet and use it. and try to save the `darkTheme()` method to the file to save the `darktheme`

Comment: but why do you think that `darkTheme();` should be quoted as a String？

Comment: I think `darkTheme()` should be converted to string so that i can use as `key` - `value` pair use.

Comment: Also never ignore exception `catch (Exception e) {
        
    }`  - at least print it out.

Comment: I print it just now and it run the `catch` clause only :(. What can I do now?

Comment: what do you think your json should look like?

Comment: `{"Theme":"darkTheme()"}` Like this

Comment: so is your code saving that in the file?

Comment: Yes. `{"Theme":"darkTheme()"}` Like this format the `config.cfg` file is created

Comment: you need to save `object.getJSONObject("Theme");` to a variable

Comment: `Object result = object.getJSONObject("Theme");` Like this?

Comment: Try reading the javadocs, people spent hundreds of hours making it for you.  https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getString-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

Ok Finally I've got a solution by my own and someone's idea.
I have changed the line in `btnDark`

```
json.put("Theme", "darkTheme();");
```

to

```
json.put("Theme", "Dark");
```

and in the `readData()` method I write like this

```
private void readData() {
    String jsonText;
    
    try {
        String path = "resources/config.cfg";
        jsonText = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(new File(path)));
        int i = jsonText.indexOf("{");
        jsonText = jsonText.substring(i);
        JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(jsonText);
        String Theme = ob.getString("Theme");
        if(Theme.equals("Dark")) {
            darkTheme();
        }
        else if(Theme.equals("Light")) {
            lightTheme();
        }
        
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And now it's work perfectly